Strapi (v4.x): Difficulty Refreshing Expired JWT Token Due to Lack of User ID
I'm facing an issue with refreshing an expired JWT token in my application. The problem is that when a token expires, I can no longer retrieve the user's ID because the token is invalid, and I need the user's ID to generate a new token.
Here's a brief overview of the situation:

Problem Description: When a user's JWT token expires, I cannot
extract the user's ID from the expired token because the
verification process fails due to the token's expiration. Without
the user ID, I can't issue a new JWT token.

Current Approach: I'm using the following approach to verify the
token and issue a new token:


 plugin.controllers.auth.refreshToken = async (ctx) => {
    const params = _.assign(ctx.request.body);

    try {
      const { id } = await strapi.plugins[
        "users-permissions"
      ].services.jwt.verify(params.jwt); // Problem retrieving user id, if token expires.

      const RAW_SQL = `SELECT id FROM up_users WHERE id = ${id}`;

      const entriesResult = await strapi.db.connection.raw(RAW_SQL);
      const rows = entriesResult.rows;

      if (_.size(rows) === 1) {
        const user = _.first(rows);

        ctx.send({
          jwt: strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.issue({
            id: user.id,
          }),
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, "Invalid token");
    }
  };


I managed to get the user id with the jsonwebtoken library
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");


const token = params.jwt;
const payload = jwt.decode(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

